# Is there a way to disable minimize/maximize button on shell in java

Tags: java, shell, swt

i want to disable minimize and maximize button on shell. I try to use setminimize function but it doesnt work. How can i do? Thank for your answers.

```
Shell shell=new Shell();
shell.setsize( 800,600);
shell.setMaximized(false); 
shell.setMinimized(false);
shell. setVisible(false);

Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT. ON_TOP) ;
browser. setUrl (helpDoc);
browser.setBounds(10,10,
764, 541);
Display display = Display getDefault); shell.open();
shell. layout();
```

Comment: (1) What is `Shell`? I can't find it among the Java standard classes, as defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). (2) The tag _shell_, without further clarification, refers to POSIX shell, and I don't see anything related to POSIX shell in your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Used shell package is org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell

Comment: Note: SWT.ON_TOP is not a valid style for `Browser` and won't do anything, only the styles defined in the [documentation for the control](https://help.eclipse.org/2022-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html) are valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the "style" of the `Shell` using the `style` parameter of the `Shell` constructor. The style specifies if the Min/Max buttons are shown. Once the shell has been created you can't change the style.

Your:

```
Shell shell = new Shell();
```

is equivalent to:

```
Shell shell = new Shell(SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
```

`SWT.SHELL_TRIM` style is defined as:

```
public static final int SHELL_TRIM = CLOSE | TITLE | MIN | MAX | RESIZE;
```

So it includes the Close button, window title, min, max buttons and allows resizing.

A common style for dialogs is `SWT.DIALOG_TRIM`:

```
public static final int DIALOG_TRIM = TITLE | CLOSE | BORDER;
```

Which leaves out the min / max.

Note: These flags are just hints to the operating system window manager. The window manager may choose to show the buttons any way. For example, on macOS min and max are always shown but min is disabled for SWT.DIALOG_TRIM.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It’s save my days and i learned lots of useful information.